# Can't get Backbone Events to work

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm using Backbone.js 1.1.2 with jQuery 1.11.

I think I'm missing something very simple.

I've set up a model: `Contact` and a collection: `ContactList`.

I have success rendering `ContactView` views with models obtained from `ContactList.fetch()`

But when I try to bind a change event in the view initializer:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

... I get:

```
backbone Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

So I go back to the documentation and read that `.on()` is part of `Backbone.Events`, and somehow I need to extend my model to use this (and why is this *not* part of the out-of-the-box functionality for models??)

I've tried declaring

```
_.extend(this, Backbone.Events);
```

... inside of the initialize function for `ContactView` before declaring the binding, but no dice.

**What do I need to do to get the Backbone.Events functionality working??**

**update: all relevant code (sans template)**

```
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        FirstName: '',
        ...[etc]
    },
    initialize: function() {
    }
});

var ContactList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,
    url: '/api/Contacts/getall'
});

var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#contact_template').html(), this.model);
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});

var contactList = new ContactList();

contactList.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response, options) {
        contactList.models.forEach(function (m) {
            var $el = $('<li />')
                .addClass('adminItem clearfix')
                .appendTo($('#contactList'));
            new ContactView({ el: $el, model: m.attributes });
        });
    }        
});
```

Comment: Backbone Models [already have the Backbone.Events mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-36). As you questioned, it would be silly if they did not. Are you sure `this.model` is a `Backbone.Model` instance?

Comment: @bejonbee: so it must be something else. I've posted more code

Comment: You might want to think about adding `tagName: 'li', className: 'adminItem clear fix'` to `ContactView`. Then `var v = new ContactView({ model: m })` and `$('#contactList').append(v.render().el)`. I find that I have a much better time when views completely own and control their own `el`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the source of trouble

```
new ContactView({ el: $el, model: m.attributes });
```

`m.attributes` [is a plain js object](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes). You want to pass along the actual model object:

```
new ContactView({ el: $el, model: m});
```

And because [the collection has underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) you should be able to simplify it a bit to this:

```
    contactList.each(function (m) {
        var $el = $('<li />')
            .addClass('adminItem clearfix')
            .appendTo($('#contactList'));
        new ContactView({ el: $el, model: m});
    });
```

Comment: Thank you much. I'd had problems getting the view to render when I assigned the model that way before. So the final bit -- I realize now -- must be to pass in `this.model.attrbutes` instead of `this.model` to unserscore's `_.template`